# heroku with carrierwave dropbox storage and rails showing always same image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, dropbox, carrierwave

so I have a web application that runs fine in development, and with carrierwave and imagemagick I make some changes on the photos that I need to upload. The problem is that when on heroku when i ask for the main version of the photo it still gives me the thumb version

```
class BannerUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  if Rails.env.development?
    storage :file
  else
    storage :dropbox
  end

  def store_dir
    if version_name.nil?
      "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}"
    else
      "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}_#{version_name}"
    end
  end

  process convert: :jpg
  process :crop
  process resize_to_limit: [1200, 260]

  def crop
    if model.crop_x.present?
      manipulate! do |img|
        x = model.crop_x.to_i
        y = model.crop_y.to_i
        w = model.crop_w.to_i
        h = model.crop_h.to_i
        r = model.crop_r.to_i
        img.rotate r
        img.crop([[w, h].join('x'), [x, y].join('+')].join('+'))
      end
    end
  end

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [640, 320]
  end

  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg png)
  end

  def filename
    if original_filename
      "#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}"
    elsif file
      file.filename
    end
  end

protected
  def secure_token
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.uuid)
  end
end
```

this is my uploader

then in my views i have `image_tag(model.banner_url(:thumb)` to get the thumb version and `image_tag @model.banner_url` to get the large version. The problem is that the second one on my local machine runs just fine, but when on heroku it gives me the same image of the first one. It does create the right folders and files, and it does crop them right, but it doesn't retrieve the correct one. I am using the

```
gem 'dropbox-sdk-v2', '~> 0.0.3'
gem 'carrierwave-dropbox', '~> 2.0'
```

as heroku storage, with obviously a dropbox account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Often you'll want to add different versions of the same file. The
>   classic example is image thumbnails. There is built in support for
>   this*

I think the problem is the way you define the store_dir method.

Define it this way:

```
def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

And also CarrierWave documentation recommends to use the uploader this way:

```
uploader = AvatarUploader.new
uploader.store!(my_file)                              # size: 1024x768

uploader.url # => '/url/to/my_file.png'               # size: 800x800
uploader.thumb.url # => '/url/to/thumb_my_file.png'   # size: 200x200
```

Source: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work... :( but thank you anyway!

Comment: You think it’s heroku problem?

Comment: I think it's more of Dropbox problem at this point, but it could actually be that...

Comment: The code seems be working well, you could try using S3 to check if is dropbox the real problem, i recommend the fog gem

Comment: Couldn’t you use aws just as a test? This way you will find what is the real problem, the store or your code

Comment: I'm glad you found the problem, i was a little sure that was on the code but in this case was the gem, happy coding!